# If I want to use zabbix for monitoring VoltDB，how can I do?

Tags: voltdb

I saw the Documentation of VoltDB. I found Nagios and New Relic, but I want to use zabbix, how can I do? I appreciate for the help!

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope for this site. We don't write tutorials, and we don't answer questions that are so vague and non-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at VoltDB.  We don't currently have a plug-in for Zabbix.  If you want to contact us at info@voltdb.com, we can discuss your requirements and log a feature request for this.